# How to Release AutoHotkey Control in a Logic Statement?

Tags: autohotkey

**Goal:**
Use the hotkey 'C' to mimmic 'New Email Window' in Outlook, similar to Gmail.

**Attempt:**

```
c::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
    If Not WinActive("Message")
        Send, ^n
return
```

**Problem:**
This script does work, but then inside that 'New Email' Window the 'c' char is locked out, and I can't use it while typing.

**Tried Solutions:**
I tried adding and empty an 'else {}' but that does not seem to work. Thoughts?

**Environment:**
Windows 10 / Outlook 2016+

Comment: It is better to use #c:: or ^c::, otherwise, the macro will trigger everytime you type c. You can add a to check if active window is Outlook, then send ^c, is that what you want?

Comment: Yep, was trying to do that check, my earlier code had this: c::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
    If (WinActive("Outlook")) && (Not WinActive("Message")) 
        Send, ^n
return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked. I think in my case it needed to know specifically what to do if the window was not active, and in my case it was to fire a regular 'c', I would have thought that logic was built in by default recognize.

```
c::
SetTitleMatchMode 2
    IfWinActive, Outlook
        Send, ^n
    Else
        send, c
return
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want,

```
SetTitleMatchMode,2
#if WinActive("Microsoft Outlook")
{
c::
   Send, ^n

   return
}
```

This way, it will allow to type the char 'c' anywhere, including the new email window. But, it will trigger if you are in the main Outlook window, opening a new email window for you.

Comment: It works in my side. Please try to change "Microsoft Outlook" to "Outlook". this way you may avoid the Send, c char, which may fire more than once

Comment: It works with Outlook 2013 and Autohotkey 1.1.26.00.

Answer (score 0):

This uses **context-sensitive title matching** to map <kbd>C</kbd> to <kbd>CTRL+N</kbd>when `"Microsoft Outlook"` is in the window title:

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2     ; All #If statements match anywhere in title
#IfWinActive Microsoft Outlook
  c::^n
#IfWinActiv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$c::
  If (WinActive("Microsoft Outlook") { ;may/may not be "Microsoft Outlook' use window spy to find out more
    send ^N ; if you got that to work then dont mess with this part
  } else {
    send {c}
  }
Return
```

Basically this checks if Outlook is active then if so sends `^N` and if not it will send the character C.

However this isnt the best idea: creating single key hotkeys that are used for typing...
Better idea: you change the hotkey ( the part before "::` ) to something like $^!c
( the $ is so that any other hotkey sending c wouldn't activate this one )

> Another aproach would be:

```
$~c::
  If (WinActive(ahk_class "outlook.exe") { ; or something along the lines of that...
    sleep 250
    send ^N
  }
Return
```

For the most part this does the same thing except it retains the functionality of the c key better, however it may cause issues with typing in outlook so once again,

> Please consider either a non-typing single key hotkey such as Rcontrol for example. The ~ in the hotkey means don't revoke original key functionality, The sleep is added to ensure that when you are using the hotkey that the retained c character isn't added to your new email.

Hope this helped ( I am fairly certain that this works ) I don't use outlook so I don't know how well Outlook will respond to this type of thing, and haven't tested this out but I do know my AHK basics and did do function syntax double checking so good luck to you, read my cmments in the code because they are essential to these code snippets functionality.

you may want to add `&& If (Not WinActive("Message"))` `;or whatwver the message window is called` if the two snippets didn't work for your needs add this because your new message window may also be called outlook so this will interfere with the typing.